# Specify the file to be compiled in VSCode Latex Workshop

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I have a folder with two `.tex` files, say `a.tex` and `b.tex` opened in VSCode.
When launching `Recipe: latexmk` (Latex Workshop extension) from the `Commands` tab, or Ctrl+Alt+B, it always compiles `a.tex` even when `b.tex` is focused in the editor.

How do I specify which `.tex` file I'd like to be compiled, if not by focusing in the editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#the-root-file) They search in multiple steps:

1. magic comment `% !TEX root =path to root.tex` -> I recommend to put it in every tex-file to assure the right file is used
2. the file with `\documentclass[...]{...}`
3. ...

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the answer can be found here: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile

My personal issue was that my `b.tex` file does not contain `\begin{document}` which Latex Workshop looks for when automatically finding the root file.